# Graph Toolkit - Clicking on folder opens a new window in mgt-file-list

Tags: microsoft-graph-toolkit

I am using mgt-file-list component and clicking on folder opens a new window.I want to stop it. I checked the code and there is a property which I need to target - disable-open-on-click which is set to false in code, see link below. That’s also not available for external to use/change. Can anyone know how to stop folder opening in new window. Only files should open in new window. We don’t want folder to open in new window.

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/blob/10b25f97ff9666bb9e0c0fadf5b453ced9da84fc/packages/mgt-components/src/components/mgt-file-list/mgt-file-list.ts#L407

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's is now an attribute, `disable-open-on-click` to suppress this behavior, once you have suppressed the default open on click, you can add your own custom behavior when items in the file list are clicked on, take a look at this story to guide you on that implementation: https://mgt.dev/?path=/story/components-mgt-file-list--events